# PHP - preg_replace YouTube embed no matter the order

Tags: php, preg-replace, amp-html, domparser

I'm trying to capture 3 elements from YouTube embed codes but sometimes those elements are not in the same order or sometimes, the embed code contains more parameters.

I'd like to find a way to extract the video ID, the width and length in order to create a YouTube integration for AMP.

Example of embed:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bpcNPHqs4ng" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Should be transformed into:

```
<amp-youtube data-videoid="bpcNPHqs4ng" width="560" height="315" 
layout="responsive"></amp-youtube>
```

If the embed was always the same it would be easy to solve but sometimes the embed code starts with the source, sometimes with the width, ... So whatever the order I would need to capture the ID, the width and the height.

Can I do this with a preg_replace in PHP ?

I tried this:

```
preg_replace('/<iframe width="([0-9]+)" height="([0-9]+)" src="https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)" (.*)><\/iframe>/', '<amp-youtube data-videoid="$3" width="$1" height="$2" layout="responsive"></amp-youtube>', $article);
```

$article contains the whole article in which the YouTube embed is used.

If a DOM parser can do the same, it's also ok for me but I'm less familiar with this.

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems right ... check https://3v4l.org/T7TDp

Comment: I would do a regex to pull all attributes into an array of key="value" in whatever order they appear, then use PHP  to build your new tag. While I'm sure it's possible to build a regex that can produce the final result directly, the complexity is going to be much easier to manage if create a simple loop instead.

Comment: @SilvioQ yes my code works but sometimes I get iframes with width, height and source in a different order so it breaks the preg_replace. I'm looking for something more agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) solution to your problem, using [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to search for `iframe` tags that have a `src` attribute that contains `youtube`, and then replacing them with a corresponding `<amp-youtube>` element:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query("//iframe[contains(@src, 'youtube')]") as $youtube) {
    // create a new node
    $node = $doc->createElement('amp-youtube');
    // set attributes
    $node->setAttribute('data-videoid', basename(parse_url($youtube->getAttribute('src'), PHP_URL_PATH)));
    $node->setAttribute('width', $youtube->getAttribute('width'));
    $node->setAttribute('height', $youtube->getAttribute('height'));
    $node->setAttribute('layout', 'responsive');
    // and now replace the old node
    $youtube->parentNode->replaceChild($node, $youtube);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output (for my demo data):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>some text</div>
    <iframe name="notyoutube" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
    <p>some more text</p> 
    <amp-youtube data-videoid="bpcNPHqs4ng" width="560" height="315" layout="responsive"></amp-youtube>
    <div>one last div</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/lNUY5)

Comment: it's an elegant solution and it's probably much better than preg_replace but I'm wondering how you could use this to replace all youtube iframes in $article with the amp-youtube. The code here displays the final amp-youtube outside the original variable. Thanks!

Comment: @Laurent please see my edit. This will modify the input HTML to replace the youtube `iframe` elements with `amp-youtube` elements.

Comment: I wish I was as good as you are :) Thanks it works perfectly. For those who are interested, I would suggest to mute warnings because domdocument doesn't like AMP documents.